# Codeigniter navigation lands in default controller when enable_query_strings is set true

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Codeigniter navigation lands in default controller when enable_query_strings is set true.

Using PHP 7
codeigniter 3.2
HMVC - wiredesignz-codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc-f77a3fc9a6fd (1)

Comment: add what you tried, how routes file looks like, add your controller files as well. Don't just say it's not working.

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: class Article extends MX_Controller
{
    /**
     * Article constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Show index article data.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Article_model', 'article');
        $this->load->view('template/layout', [
            'title' => 'Articles',
            'page' => 'index',
            'articles' => $this->article->getAllArticles()
        ]);
    }

Comment: class Author extends MX_Controller
{
    /**
     * Author constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Show index author data.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Author_model', 'author');
        $this->load->view('template/layout', [
            'title' => 'Authors',
            'page' => 'index',
            'authors' => $this->author->getAllAuthors()
        ]);
    }

Comment: $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

Comment: I need the query strings to be enabled for the project. The code is working on regular case but when the query strings is set to true its not navigating.